# LibreOffice super/subscripts in axis labels

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to use superscripts or subscripts in plot axis labels in LibreOffice Calc? If not, is there a good work-around that will produce the same effect?

Comment: I did find one work-around is to insert a secondary axis with appropriately spaced superscripts (or subscripts, but not both) and position it relative to the main axis-label.

Comment: Post that as an answer, then

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what characters you need, you might be able [to use Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts):

> Consolidated for cut-and-pasting purposes, the Unicode standard defines complete sub- and super-scripts for numbers and common mathematical symbols ( ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎ ), a full superscript Latin lowercase alphabet except q ( ᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ ), a limited uppercase Latin alphabet ( ᴬ ᴮ ᴰ ᴱ ᴳ ᴴ ᴵ ᴶ ᴷ ᴸ ᴹ ᴺ ᴼ ᴾ ᴿ ᵀ ᵁ ⱽ ᵂ ), a few subscripted lowercase letters ( ₐ ₑ ₕ ᵢ ₖ ₗ ₘ ₙ ₒ ₚ ᵣ ₛ ₜ ᵤ ᵥ ₓ ), and some Greek letters ( ᵅ ᵝ ᵞ ᵟ ᵋ ᶿ ᶥ ᶲ ᵠ ᵡ ᵦ ᵧ ᵨ ᵩ ᵪ ). Note that since these glyphs come from different ranges, they may not be of the same size and position, depending on the typeface.

Answer (score 4):

this is problem. In my case, I use two approaches - first is to insert the graph in Draw as metafile, disconnect it to get the particular elements and then edit the labels. Or create graph without labels, insert it as image in Draw and add labels.

Second method is to create entire graph in other program - I use [Scidavis](http://scidavis.sourceforge.net/), which is free and opensource:

[image]

because I sometimes need more advanced features and in Scidavis is no problem to use superscripts or subscripts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I suspected that it would not be possible to do this in LibreOffice Calc itself.